# How to fix USB gamepad problem with Sega Mega Drive (Genesis) Classics 1

Tags: technical-issues, controllers, sega-genesis-classics

Lately I bought Sega Mega Drive Classics 1 on [Get Games](http://www.getgamesgo.com/), featuring Golden Axe, Shadow Dancer, Crack Down and several others (also available on Steam).

The games work perfectly with my ancient, game-port based gamepad, though since it is a little worn out, I decided to try a much more recent Hama USB based gamepad instead. It works pretty good in Control Panel->Game Controllers options (calibrated, all buttons and analogs working properly), but when I launch the Sega Mega Drive Collection 1 emulator, the controls go crazy, as if the pad was completely uncalibrated. The same happens when I somewhat succeed to run any of the games.

Is the Sega Mega Drive Collection packages known to have issues when used with USB gamepads? Is there a way to fix the problem?

Comment: Wait, you actually have a working controller that still uses an old PC game port? I didn't know any motherboards or PCI cards still came with those! There are lots of very good USB controllers though, and of course USB adapters for every game console's controllers. All available cheaply on eBay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an actual answer, but a workaround. You can try using [Xpadder](http://www.xpadder.com/) to map your joystick to keyboard keys.

Of course, that will only work if you can disable the in-game joystick support. Since I don't own Sega Mega Drive Classics, I don't know if that's possible, and probably I can't help you further than that.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Xpadder does not seem too happy to work with 2 gamepads connected at the same time (I have also an Interact PC Propad 4 connected to game port, apart from the USB gamepad), which makes it quite uncomfortable to use - I would have to unplug/disconnect the game port pad every time I would want to play Sega Mega Drive Collection.

Comment: Weird. Xpadder here seems to work perfectly fine with multiple joysticks connected to the system. You can just leave the second gamepad with no mappings, so that it won't generate any keypresses.

Comment: Just in case you haven't figured it out, each joystick has a "visual layout" associated with it. In addition, it has a "key mapping" also associated. That way, you can have a different mapping for each different game you play, using the same joystick. Of course, a "blank" mapping is also possible (and sometimes desirable).